# Adding new records to a Phalcon model not correctly creating the relation

Tags: php, phalcon

I having a `1:n` relationship between a `Client` and `Addresses`. A client can have many addresses.

I have created the following models:

```
class Client extends ModelBase
{    
    $this->hasMany("id", "ClientAddress", "client_id", array(
      "alias" => "addresses"
    ));

class ClientAddress extends ModelBase
{

  public function initialize()
  {
    parent::initialize();                                              
    $this->belongsTo("client_id", "Client", "id", array(
      "alias" => "client"
    ));

    $this->belongsTo("address_id", "Address", "id", array(
      "alias" => "address"
    ));
  }

class Address extends ModelBase
{
```

I want to perform some CRUD operations on the `Address`.

I've tried to create a new `Address` and have it link to the `ClientAddress` using the following. It does create the record in the `Address` table, but it doesn't link to it through the `ClientAddress` table.

```
$client = Client::findFirst($current_client_id);
$address = new Address();
$address->setName( $this->request->getPost("name") );
$address->setAddress1( $this->request->getPost("address1") );
$address->setAddress2( $this->request->getPost("address2") );
$address->setSuburb( $this->request->getPost("suburb") );
$address->setState( $this->request->getPost("state") );
$address->setPostcode( $this->request->getPost("postcode") );
$address->setCountry( $this->request->getPost("country") );

$client->addresses = $address;
$client->save();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Many to many relations are an array of relationships. One subtle change and everything should work.

```
$client->addresses[] = $address;
$client->save();
```

Sidebar:

I think Benjamin raises a valid point about the association of the address however. Think about websites like amazon where you get to pick from a list of addresses to ship to. They are associated to your account, not to your previous orders.

I've built several eCommerce and CRM ties before so pretty used to this pattern.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure what point is being made about the address association. Sure, you can select a previously saved address which is associated to your account (or in my case, your client), but it ultimately has to end up associated against the order. In my case, I can have multiple addresses on an order which is why I need the intermediate table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for an 1:n relation you do not need a cross table.

Try somthing like this

```
class Client extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

   public function initialize()
   {
   $this->hasMany('id', 'Address', 'client_id', NULL);
   }
}


class Address extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model{

   public function initialize()
   {
   $this->belongsTo('client_id', 'Client', 'id', array('foreignKey' => true));

   }
}
```

edit:

```
class Client extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{


    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany("id", "ClientAddress", "client_id");
    }

}


class Address extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{


    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany("id", "ClientAddress", "address_id");
    }

}


class ClientAddress extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{


    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo("client_id", "Client", "id");
        $this->belongsTo("address_id", "Address", "id");
    }

}
```

Calls can be made this way

```
$client = Client::findFirst($current_client_id);
$address = new Address();
...
$address->save();
$clientAddress  = new ClientAddress ();

$clientAddress->setClient_id($client->getId());
$clientAddress->setAddress_id($cddress_id->getId());
$clientAddress->save();
```

Maybe add some checks and rollbacks, when somethings goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks. But the thing is, these Address records are not just used on Clients- they are used on other things such as Orders etc, which is why I have the cross table.

Comment: Think about your logic. Thinks like orders shoud have a relations to a Client not an address.

Comment: Orders have addresses (multiple addresses are allowed). So I will have the same cross table for orders, called order_addresses.